# SQL LIKE issue it selects 1, 10 and 11 if i want to select 1 from my user_id's

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm not really familiar with SQL and right now i have a problem with my query and it drives me insane i have 11 records with id and the id is just 1, 2, 3, .... and now if i have this query i want it to only output the record with id 1 but it also outputs records 10 and 11

This is my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id LIKE ?
```

and the bind parameter is:

```
$id
```

which in this case is 1 `($_GET['id'])`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: tr `id = ?` instead, which provides a more exact comparison. `like` is just, well... *like*

Comment: If i do that it won't output anything at al @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Show your binding. Are you concatenating? Also `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: then your database has some problems. could you please provide your table structure, some sample data and a `var_dump($id)`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If the binding appends `%`s the query won't match with the `=`.

Comment: oh i just figured out i could maybe use LIMIT 1

Comment: @chri85 why should the binding ever append `%`? that's no behaviour i have ever encountered

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If the OP appends it, not the driver. Because without it the `like` is `=`.

Comment: this is my binding variable: '%' . $id . '%'

Comment: @A.Mousavi no. don't do that. by using LIMIT with a LIKE statement, you don't have any guarantees that you actually retreive the one dataset you *want*

Comment: @A.Mousavi That is the issue with the `=`s, take out the `%`s. The `%`s are for partial matches. Do you want those? Also don't do that `limit` approach.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks i tried just $id now and it works thanks for you help! cause now i can use a WHERE = statement

Comment: Not possible. `where x like 1` is execute as the equivalent of `where x=1`. There's no wildcards, so you should **NOT** get `10` back. `select 1 like 10` evaluates to FALSE.

Comment: You have 3 RDMS tagged BTW....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like does pattern matching and is used in conjunction with wildcard keys to find similar results. You are looking for an exact value, so just directly compare with an equal sign:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =
```

Using like, you could find anything containing a 1

```
id like '%1%'
```

or two digits where the first digit is a 1

```
id like '1_'
```

Here is the docs on TSQL's like operator. But think you just need =...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to replace "LIKE" by "=" in your query

Comment: I was going to post, but he should really be using a paramterized statement, rather than a raw `WHERE` clause.